# $U(f,K,\epsilon)=\{g:g\in L$ and $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in K\}$, is Let $C=\{U(f,K,\epsilon)\}$. Is $T=\{\cup B, B\in C\}$ a topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $L$ be the set of all continuous real-valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$. For every compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$, $f\in L$, and positive number $\epsilon >0$ let

$U(f,K,\epsilon)=\{g:g\in L$ and $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in K\}$

Let $C=\{U(f,K,\epsilon): K$ is compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $f\in L, \epsilon >0\}$. Further, let $T=\{\cup B, B \text{ is a subcollection of } C\}$. Is $T$ a topology for $L$?

What I tried:

I think it's a topology.

$\emptyset\in T$, since $\emptyset$ is the union of empty subcollection of $L$.

$L\in T$, since $f(x)=0$ is continuous, and every continuous function on a compact set is bounded, so for every continuous function $g$, exists $\epsilon >0$, s.t. $|g(x)-0|<\epsilon$ on a compact set.

Arbitrary union in $T$: since by defniton of $T$, $\cup\cup B=\cup B\in T$.

But I don't know how to show that $\cap^n_1(\cup B)\in T$.

（I don't quite sure whether $f$ in $C$ is fixed or not, if $f$ is fixed, then this question seem to be easy.)

Comment: To prove this, you can assume without loss of generality that $B_1, \dots , B_n$ are composed by a single element. In other words, you have to show that if $B_1, \dots , B_n \in C$, then $B_1 \cap \dots \cap B_n \in T$. This is a basic fact in topology, it relies on the concept of *basis for a topology*. Do you know what is a basis for a topology?

Comment: @Crostul I know basis, but this question comes before the definition of basis in the book. But even with basis, if $f$ is fixed, to prove $B_1 \cap \dots \cap B_n \in T$ is easy, is it just using the smallest $\epsilon $ of $B_i$? But if $f$ is not fixed, I don't know how to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that in the definition of the family $C$, $ f$  is not fixed. We claim that $C$ is a basis of a topology on $L$. To show this, for each $f\in L$ and each elements $U(f_1,K_1,\epsilon_1),\dots, U(f_n,K_n,\epsilon_n)$ containing $f$ there exists a compact subset $K$ of $\Bbb R$ and $\delta>0$ such that $U(f,K, delta)\subset U(f_i,K_i,\epsilon_i)$ for each $1\le i\le n$.
For each such $i$, a function $g_i(x)=|f_i(x)-f(x)|$ is a continuous function on a compact set $K_i$, so it attains it maximum $m_i$ at some point $x_i$ of $K_i$. Since $g_i(x_i)<\epsilon_i$, there exists $\delta_i>0$ such that $m_i+\delta_i<\epsilon_i$. Put $K=K_1\cup\dots K_n$ and $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\dots, \delta_n\}$. Let $g\in (f,K, \delta)$ be any function. Pick any  $1\le i\le n$ and any $x\in K_i$. Then
$$|g(x)-f_i(x)|\le |g(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f_i(x)|<\delta+m_i<\delta_i+m_i<\epsilon_i,$$
so $g\in U(f_i,K_i,\epsilon_i)$.